# Imagick Operations Slow?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I was experimenting with https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.sharpenimage.php and it was so. very. slow.

For instance, it was taking almost 40 seconds to sharpen an image that is about 600px by 800px.

All I'm doing is...

```
$image = new Imagick('path/to/image/blah.png');
$image->sharpenimage(50, 1);
```

Is this sort of thing normal for Image Magick?

---

I did some deeper testing, and it seems that the value of `sharpenimage` impacts the results dramatically!

```
$image->sharpenimage(5, 1); → 2-3 seconds
$image->sharpenimage(10, 1); → 3 seconds
$image->sharpenimage(20, 1); → 7 seconds
$image->sharpenimage(30, 1); → 16 seconds
$image->sharpenimage(40, 1); → 38 seconds
$image->sharpenimage(50, 1); → 50 seconds
```

The somewhat linear relationship makes sense I guess.  If anyone has any other insight on this, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: So generally image operations are very intensive computationally really depends upon size and complexity of the image or the hardware you're running on or the specific settings you use for the image processing operations. Can you reduce the sharpening parameters or resize the image before sharpening? What's are the requirements?

Comment: Maybe try outside of PHP an in Terminal, using `magick blah.png -sharpen 50x1 result.jpg` and see if it is your hardware or something within PHP.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: It's a shared hosting environment, so I don't think I'd have that option.  Or were you referring to some outside testing environment?

Answer (score 0):

You should check and see how much memory you are dedicating to a PHP file, you could be nearing your limit.

Try,

`ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');`

I've used the GD2 library for PHP and when sharpening or modifying an image I never had it be that slow except for when it was capping out memory. Then again this is a different library. Consider using GD2 as it comes with PHP